Given a group $G = \langle a,b,c\mid a^3, c^4 , c(ab)^2ca^{-1}\rangle$, show the existence of the homomorphism $\varphi : G \rightarrow S_6$
Given that $G = \langle a,b,c\mid a^3, c^4 , c(ab)^2ca^{-1}\rangle$,
show that there is a homomorphism $\varphi : G \rightarrow S_6$, such that $\varphi(a) = (1, 3, 5)(2, 4, 6),$ $\varphi(b) = (1, 2, 3, 4)$ and $\varphi(c) = (2, 5)$
This is for an assignment for my maths degree. We have previously covered things like generating sets, group actions, direct products of group and things alike. We more recently covered Free Groups i.e trees, spanning tree, graph folding etc. I cannot seem to remember (or find within my notes) an example like it therefore I am stumped.
I assume it has nothing to do with trees and graphs (which were used in previous questions of this assignment) however more to do with generating sets but am totally unsure. A push in the right direction is massively appreciated
##################################################
Been in contact with my professor and have been informed the content I need to answer this hasn't been covered yet, apologies to all

Here's a MathJax tutorial :)

If you set $d=ab$ it simplifies the representation a little.

@ThomasAndrews *presentation

After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: How do I accept an answer?, Why should we accept answers?, What should I do if someone answers my question?.

Please edit your post to make clear what you understand by $$\langle a,b,c\mid a^3, c^4 , c(ab)^2ca^{-1}\rangle.$$ In view of this assignment, you are supposed to know the definition of a presentation of group, so this post should be useless.

Show that $\varphi(a) = (1, 3, 5)(2, 4, 6),$ $\varphi(b) = (1, 2, 3, 4)$ and $\varphi(c) = (2, 5)$ satisfy the relations of $G$ and generate $S_6$.
Homomorphisms are determined by their values on generators.
